# php массив ближайшие

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
```

Нужна красивая функция, которая будет возвращать:

- При параметре `8` - массив `Array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)`,
- При параметре `12` - массив `Array(10, 11, 12, 13, 15)`,
- При параметре `1` - массив `Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`,
- При параметре `2` - массив `Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`,
- При параметре `15` - массив `Array(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)`,
- При параметре `14` - массив `Array(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)`

Comment: Что вы уже пытались сделать и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: сортируйте по модулю разности и берите первые 5 элементов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

эмм

```
function returnClosest($array, $position, $offset = 2){
    $position--;
    if(($position + $offset * 2 + 1) > count($array)){
        $position = count($array) - ($offset + 1);//10 - 2
    }
    return array_slice($array, $position - $offset, $offset * 2 + 1);
}
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);

var_dump(returnClosest($arr, 10));
var_dump(returnClosest($arr, 5));
var_dump(returnClosest($arr, 1));
//Получаем результаты, приведенные ниже
```

`array(5) ( 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 )`
`array(5) ( 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 )`
`array(5) ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )`